# Merging two DF's on shortest date record and delete non-matching date rows

Tags: python, pandas, merge, multiple-columns, missing-data

i have two df's that i need to merge into one new df based on the day, month and year of the df with the shortest record of day, month and year. In other words, if the "day", "month" and "year" columns do not match in the comparison then i need to delete those rows or do not match. The df with the longest record or rows of day, month and year is "ncm" df and looks like this:

```
ncm.head()
Out[358]: 
  plant_name  month  year    power_kwh
0  ALBUREJOS      1  2018  2634.583602
1  ALBUREJOS      1  2019  1947.384812
2  ALBUREJOS      1  2020  1787.296640
3  ALBUREJOS      2  2018  1539.008929
4  ALBUREJOS      2  2019  4948.003274
```

and, the second df that i need to merge with some missing data and shorter number of dates (day, month and year) is df "dfm" and looks like this:

```
dfm.head()
Out[359]: 
  plant_name  month  year  power_obs_kwh
0  ALBUREJOS      1  2018    2631.353970
1  ALBUREJOS      1  2019    1931.685916
2  ALBUREJOS      1  2020    1750.192298
3  ALBUREJOS      1  2021     314.000000
4  ALBUREJOS      2  2018    1537.588323
```

I have tried multiple iterations of things like this below and have reached this error shown also here.

```
new_df = dfm.merge(ncm, left_on=['month','year'], right_on = ['power_kwh'], how='left')
```

error message:

```
ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)
```

thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), parameters `left_on` and `right_on` must be the columns you want to use to join the two DataFrames, so they have to be the same. In your case since the columns have the same name you can use `on` instead

```
dfm.merge(ncm, on=['month','year'])
```

for example

```
np.random.seed(42)
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 13), 100),
    'year': np.random.choice(np.arange(2010, 2019), 100),
    'some_data_1': np.random.random(100)
})
np.random.seed(33)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'month': np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 13), 100),
    'year': np.random.choice(np.arange(2010, 2019), 100),
    'some_data_2': np.random.random(100)
})
```

and then we simply do

```
df_1.merge(
    df_2,
    on=['month', 'year']
)
```

which gives

```
     month  year  some_data_1  some_data_2
0        7  2018     0.242055     0.646164
1        7  2018     0.649633     0.646164
2        4  2016     0.672136     0.936810
3       11  2018     0.761620     0.419030
4       11  2018     0.761620     0.533564
..     ...   ...          ...          ...
101      9  2010     0.853009     0.856196
102      9  2010     0.853009     0.602498
103      9  2010     0.853009     0.713095
104      5  2015     0.428184     0.377500
105     12  2010     0.294449     0.455945

[106 rows x 4 columns]
```